# Python IDE that allows for right-click -> Go to Declaration and Find References?

Tags: python, ide

Is there a python IDE that allows you to right click on any method being used and select Go to Declaration or Find References, just like in Visual Studio with all of the .net languages?

I am finding it difficult to navigate another developer's django project without this ability.

Comment: If you want "just like Visual Studio", why not use Visual Studio? IronPython is a .NET language, and it's Python. It may not be the _same_ Python implementation that the other developer is using to run Django, but so what?

Comment: Will IronPython work with an existing regular-python django project?

Comment: It probably can't _run_ the project… but who cares? You don't normally run a Django server inside an IDE anyway. If it can parse the code and do the intellisense-type stuff, that's all that matters, right? (And before you ask whether it can… I don't know, but you presumably have Visual Studio, and can test it as easily as I could.)

Answer (score 2):

PyDev (an Eclipse Plugin) allows you to press F3 and you'll go to the highlighted element's definition.

And PyDev comes with some nice django support features like running manage.py commands, setting up apps, etc.

Comment: Fairly certain you can also do the 'right click,  goto definition' in PyDev as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using PyCharm for the past year and am very satisfied with the features included, coming from Visual Studio myself. It has got what you are requesting and more. It is not free, but there is a trial version. In my opinion money well spent.

It has also got some Django support, but I've never used it myself.

Answer (score 0):

In windows I've been using PyScripter and like it. It brings up the function definition on mouseover and allows you to jump to it if you want. Also has 'find references' in the right click context menu. It's free.

Answer (score 0):

Wing IDE has both goto-definition (F4) and find points of use (right click on the symbol for a popup menu or bind a key sequence to the command find-points-of-use if using a keyboard personality that doesn't already have a binding).  Wing also provides related functionality like rename refactoring, move symbol, etc.  It is a commercial product but you can get a 30-day free trial to try it out at http://wingware.com/